# How to add number next to slash using css and react?

Tags: css, reactjs

i want to add a number next to slash such that it looks like below

[image]

I have tried like below

```
render = () => {
    return (
        <Text size={25} weight={700} color={availableMobileUserCountColor}>
            {availableMobileUsersCount}
        </Text>
        <Text size={14} weight={700} color={theme.colors.text}>
            /40
        </Text>
    )
}
```

And the Text component returns span element

```
const Text = styled.span<Props>`
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: ${p => p.size || 16}px;
    font-weight: ${props => props.weight || 400};
    color: ${props => props.color};
`;
```

For the above code, it looks like this,

[image: rendered output]

As you see, the slash and number 40 are up they should be below..how can i do it.could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the `flex` of the display property. It is not in `reactjs` but it will give you the idea.

```css
.figure {
  display:flex;
  align-items:baseline
 }
 
 .first {
  font-size:28px;
  color:orange;
  font-weight:800;
 }
 
 .second {
  font-size:16px
  color:#000;
  font-weight:600;
 }
```

```html
<div class="figure"><span class="first">2</span> <span class="second"> /71</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sub](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sub.asp) tag

```js
return <p>{availableMobileUsersCount}<sub>/40</sub</p>;
```